# Haskell: How would I add input value from a function to a global list?

Tags: haskell

I am basically making a task manager where a user can add a task or print out all tasks entered.
my main function contains the options of what users do...

```
main = do
   
   putStrLn "Below are the Options:\n\tadd\n\tprint\n\tsearch\nEnter Option:"

   input <- getLine 
   
   if input == "add" then 

       buildList []
       

   else if input == "print" then

    putStrLn "printing"

   else if input == "search" then

    putStrLn "searching"

   else
       putStrLn "Please Enter add, print, search"
   main
```

I am working on a function called buildList where the creation of the task happens:

```
buildList tasks = do
    putStrLn "Enter a Task:"

    input <- getLine

    let mytask = input

    putStrLn mytask  --here to prevent an error
```

..and I assume I would need a global list since I will need it if I want to print out or search within it.

```
mytasklist = []
```

I have been stuck on this for a while as I am new to functional programming and Haskell.  I understand that I can add two list together with ++ or just do : to add at the start of the list, but I cant seem to figure out how to achieve this without an error.

update1: so would something like this work?

```
buildList tasks = do
    putStrLn "Enter a Task:"
    input <- getLine

    let updatedTasks = tasks ++ [input]

    main

main = do
   
   putStrLn "Below are the Options:\n\tadd\n\tprint\n\tsearch\nEnter Option:"

   input <- getLine 
   
   if input == "add" then do

    buildList []

   else if input == "print" then

    putStrLn "searchiwng"

   else if input == "search" then

    putStrLn "searching"

   else
       putStrLn "Please Enter add, print, search"
   main
```

Comment: As you noticed a global variable doesn't make a lot of sense, as they are immutable. Instead you would need to to have an explicit state that you take, transform and return again in each iteration. Furthermore I'd recommend loking into the  `case` expression and guards that would simplify your `if else` construction.

Comment: Your question is how to have a global list you can access from everywhere?

Comment: If possible yes, in my mind as of now I would like to go through my buildlist function then append the global list with the value the user made in buildlist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler example, where you can increase or print an integer.
You could try to adapt it to your task.

The trick is the recursive function `loop`, which calls itself with the updated integer.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let loop :: Int -> IO ()
       loop n = do
          putStrLn "print/inc/quit?"
          opt <- getLine
          case opt of
             "print" -> do print n; loop n   -- recurse with the same n
             "inc"   -> loop (n+1)           -- recurse with updated n
             "quit"  -> putStrLn "bye!"      -- don't recurse to stop
             _       -> do putStrLn "invalid option, try again"; loop n
   -- call loop prividing the intial value
   loop 0
```

You can also make `loop` into a top-level function, and simply define `main = loop 0`, if you prefer.

There are, of course, several other more advanced options in Haskell to do this, but I'd recommend you start with the above basic approach.

When you are more familiar with the language, you could try the following alternative options:

- the `StateT Int IO` monad allows IO operations and reading/writing to an `Int` state
- `IORef`s can also be used to model mutable data

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `loop` can be a top-level function and `main = loop 0`.

Comment: I've seen `do` used to [replace parentheses](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/nw40cz/comment/h16zgsj/), but I've never seen it used to replace `in` before!

Comment: @jlwoodwa Inside `do a;b;c` each item can be of the form `var <- monadicAction`, `monadicAction` alone (with an implicit `_ <-` in front), and `let var = expr` with no `in`. The very last item must be `monadicAction`. Note that we can write `let` without `in` in list comprehensions too.

Answer (score 4):

You need to rename your `main` function to something else, lets say `go` (seems to be the traditional name for this pattern) and pass your task list as a parameter to `go`. In the case of "add" the list you pass is the old list plus the new entry.

(Obviously this is a toy problem for learning, and this is a toy solution. Real programs have more sophisticated approaches. But this will do for now).